# Base64 string to NSData then gunzip

Tags: ios, gzip, nsdata

I have a base64 encoded NSString of the binary, which I convert to an NSData object, using @mattt's [Godzippa](https://github.com/mattt/Godzippa) class I am trying to gunzip the nsdata but I get an error:

`Error Domain=com.godzippa.zlib.error Code=-3 "Error inflating payload" UserInfo=0x881b0b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error inflating payload}`

When I investigated further the `zStream.msg` is `msg = 0x000164de "incorrect header check"`

But I am having troubles understanding what the incorrect header check means and how I can fix this issue. I appoligize in advance for the lack of detail, if someone can walk me through understanding the issues here I will promptly answer any questions.

Here is how I'm doing it, i removed the base64 string however:

```
NSString *dataString = @"REMOVED BASE64 STRING HERE";

NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:dataString];

NSError *error = nil;

NSData *decompressed = [data dataByGZipDecompressingDataWithError:&error];

if(error){
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was trying to decompress a zlib archive when I needed to decompress a gzip file. Specifically I had to change the `inflateInit()` to the `inflatateInit2()` method in the libz/gzip library.

Answer (score 1):

I have some code that does exactly what you looking for (gunzip not unzip). You can find the source on GitHub [here](http://bit.ly/YdN5a9) and a line by line description on my blog [here](http://bit.ly/16whk30).